# Ubuntu 19.10 is using "manually installed display drivers", how do I uninstall/change it?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I somehow installed some 32-bit display drivers and they are terrible (4fps on Minecraft and laggy on Desktop). When I open `Additional Drivers`, it shows that instead of `nvidia-driver-440` being used, it's a manually installed driver and the other options are greyed out. How do I use the other options or just uninstall the 32-bit ones?
I've tried seeing what it's using with `lshw -c video` but that just shows `nvidia`.

edit: ran Minecraft, apparently it's using VMWare drivers??

[image]

edit2: uninstalled the vmware drivers (didn't think of that at first because I thought I installed some Nvidia ones by accident) 
 if you come across this same issue, what I did was run `dpkg -l | grep -i 'vmware'` which outputted `xserver-xorg-video-vmware`, then I just run `sudo apt remove (package)`

Comment: `lshw -c display` may give a bit more information.

Comment: @dragosht your command shows [this](https://i.imgur.com/HxhHRlC.png)